# Grouping css selectors for the same elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wonder if instead of having something like this:

```
#class1 ul li, #class2 ul li, #class3 ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

it is possible to do something like this:

```
(#class1, #class2, #class3) ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

This doesn't work, but I wonder if there's any syntax for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly there is no such syntax. For such kinds of css minimizing, some tools (languages) were developed, like Less and Sass. You write css styles in special syntax that later translated into common css. Your example seems to be a :nested rules" in less - [see the link](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules)

```
#class1, #class2, #class3 {
     ul li {
           display: inline;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you care to provide an example in such languages?

Comment: Yes, i've added a link to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a class selecter, and group the corresponding elements by using the same class attribute.

For example:

```
<div class = "car" id = "car1"></div>
<div class = "car" id = "car2"></div>
<div class = "car" id = "car3"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.car { display: block;}
```